# Find the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}\sum\limits_{k=n}^{3n} \binom{k-1}{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-n}$

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

The problem is to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\sum\limits_{k=n}^{3n} \binom{k-1}{n-1} \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^n \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{k-n}$$

I see that it looks similarly to the formula from the binomial theorem, but don't get how we can make use of it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no standard way to use the $C_i^j$ symbol. By $C_{k-1}^{n-1}$, do you mean the number of ways to choose $k-1$ things from $n-1$ things? If so, note that all terms other than the first one in the sum are zero. If you mean the reverse, note that each term in the sum is non-negative, so the sum itself is at least $\binom{3n-1}{n-1} 2^{2n}/3^n$ (which is the very last term), which goes to infinity with $n$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I meant the latter one (edited the question accordingly).  But the upper bound you provided is not correct - in denominator there should be $3^{3n}$.

Comment: I would suggest trying to find a combinatorial interpretation for the sum - an individual term is, for instance, $\frac nk$ times the probability of rolling exactly $n$ `1`s in $k$ rolls of a 3-sided die.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum over all integers is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n\left(\frac23\right)^{k-n}
&=\left(\frac13\right)^n\sum_{k=n}^\infty(-1)^{k-n}\binom{-n}{k-n}\left(\frac23\right)^{k-n}\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-n}{k}\left(-\frac23\right)^k\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)^n\left(\frac13\right)^{-n}\\[9pt]
&=1\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\frac{\binom{k}{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n\left(\frac23\right)^{k-n+1}}{\binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n\left(\frac23\right)^{k-n}}=\frac23\frac{k}{k-n+1}\tag{2}
$$
which is $1$ when $k\approx3n$. That is, the summand is at its maximum near $k\approx3n$. By the [method of Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), the sum to the maximum tends to one half the total sum, so we get that
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n\left(\frac23\right)^{k-n}=\frac12}\tag{3}
$$

---

**Application of Laplace's Method**

Let
$$
f_n(k)=\binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n\left(\frac23\right)^{k-n}\tag{4}
$$
From $(3)$, we can derive that for $k-3n=O\!\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(f_n(k+1))-\log(f_n(k))
&=\log\left(\frac23\frac{k}{k-n+1}\right)\\
&=\log\left(\frac{1+\frac{k-3n}{3n}}{1+\frac1{6n}+\frac{k-3n}{2n}}\right)\\
&=\log\left(1-\frac{k-3n}{6n}\right)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\\
&=-\frac{k-3n}{6n}+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
From $(5)$, we get that
$$
f_n(k)=c\,e^{-\frac{(k-3n)^2}{12n}+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)}\tag{6}
$$
Since the sum for all $k$ of $f_n(k)$ is $1$, we get
$$
f_n(k)=\frac1{\sqrt{12\pi n}}\,e^{-\frac{(k-3n)^2}{12n}}+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{7}
$$
Since $(7)$ is symmetric about $k=3n$, the sum for $k\lt3n$ will be approximately the same as the sum for $k\gt3n$. Thus, the sum for $k\lt3n$ will be approximately $\frac12$.

Comment: Very nice! (+1) Could you provide a reference regarding the methods of stationary phase?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: actually, since the exponent is real, it should be Laplace's Method. That is, since $\frac23\frac{k}{k-n+1}=\frac{2(k-3n)+6n}{3(k-3n)+6n+1}\approx1-\frac{k-3n}{6n}$, we have $\binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n\left(\frac23\right)^{k-n}\approx\frac1{\sqrt{12\pi n}}e^{-\frac{(k-3n)^2}{12n}}$ when $k\approx3n$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the info. Best regards,

Comment: Stationary Phase and Laplace's Method are related by a rotation in the complex plane. I sometimes cite one instead of the other. Note that I did add a link to my answer.

Comment: Great, instructive elaboration! Many thanks! :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer There is a nice account of "Laplace Method for Sums" in the book "Analytic Combinatorics" by Flajolet and Sedgewick, Cambridge University Press 2009. Page $\color{#f00}{\mbox{761}}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Many thanks for the hint, Felix. I will read it, I mean enjoy it, of course! :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer ${\Large{\bullet\quad\bullet \atop {\mid \atop {\Huge\smile}}}}$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Could someone please elaborate more on what exactly the $\approx$ symbol means in this context? Does this proof pretend to be absolutely rigorous or it just claims that the limit is "approximately $\frac{1}{2}$" (as it said at the end of the answer)?
Also, how (6) follows from (5)? And why (7) implies that the limit in question is $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Ramil: I have removed the $\approx$ and replaced it with [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\{\xi_i, i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ -- iid $\mathrm{Geom}\left(\frac13\right)$ variables ($\xi_i \geq 1$).

$$
\Pr\left(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \xi_i \leq 3n \right) = \sum\limits_{k = n}^{3n}\Pr\left(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \xi_i = k \right) = \sum\limits_{k = n}^{3n} \binom{k - 1}{n - 1}\left(\frac13\right)^n \left(\frac23\right)^{k - n} 
$$
It is so because we iterate from $n$ to $3n$ (these are the all possible variants for the sum of $n$ geometric variables). Then there are $\binom{k - 1}{n - 1}$ variants to have the needed sum (stars and bars method) and the probability of each variant is really obvious because all of the variables have $1/3$ in pmf and other sum in exponent is overall $k - n$.

So, our answer is (remember that $\mathsf{E}\xi_i = 3$)

$$
\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \Pr\left(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \xi_i \leq 3n \right) = \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \Pr\left(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (\xi_i - \mathsf{E}\xi_i) \leq 0 \right) = \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}\Pr\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n(\xi_i - \mathsf{E}\xi_i)}{\sqrt{n\mathsf{D}\xi_1}} \leq 0 \right)
$$

The equation under the probability converges in distribution (due to central limit theorem) to $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and obviously the limit is $1/2$ because $\Pr(X \leq 0) = \frac12$.