# A non-probabilistic take on $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=n}^{5n}{k-1\choose n-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-n}$

Tags: limits, contest-math, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I saw this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555380/find-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-n5nk-1-choose-n-1-left-frac15-ri) and I tried it on my own. I don't have a background in Probability theory, so I tried to employ algebra only to evaluate this limit.

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=n}^{5n}{k-1\choose n-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-n}$$

---

**My Attempt**:

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=n}^{5n}{k-1\choose n-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-n}&=\frac{1}{5^n}\sum_{k=0}^{4n} {k+n-1\choose n-1} \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k}\\ &=\frac{1}{5^n}\left(\text{coeff. of }x^{n-1} \text{ in }\sum_{k=0}^{4n}(1+x)^{k+n-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k\right)\\ &=\frac{1}{5^n}\left[\text{coeff. of }x^{n-1} \text{ in } \left((1+x)^{n-1}\frac{\left(\frac{4}{5}(1+x)\right)^{4n+1}-1}{\left(\frac{4}{5}(1+x)\right)-1}\right)\right]\end{aligned}$$

---

I don't know how to proceed because computing the coefficient in the above term is a really long task. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=n}^{5n}{k-1\choose n-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-n}&=\frac{1}{5^n}\sum_{k=0}^{4n} {k+n-1\choose n-1} \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k}\\ &=\frac{1}{5^n}\left(\text{coeff. of }x^{n-1} \text{ in }\sum_{k=0}^{4n}(1+x)^{k+n-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k\right)\end{aligned}$$

therefore what you re after is

=$\frac{1}{5^n} \sum_{k=0}^{4n}{n-1\choose k+n-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k $

Comment: That would be ${k+n-1\choose n-1}$. But this is same as what I started with.

Comment: i dont think you can simplify any further ,